# Rust Iterration over Vector and Ownership

Tags: rust, iterator

I had been learning Rust recently.

I stumbled across the following code:

```
pub fn to_bytes(values: &[u32]) -> Vec<u8> {
    for &(mut value) in values {
        //...
    }
}
```

I do not understand the `&` in the `for` loop. What exactly is happening here?

I figured out that if you iterate over a vector, using a for loop, you get a reference ([found here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/book/iterators.html)):

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
for value in &v {
    // value is a reference 
}
```

Then why do I need another `&` in the first snipped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I figured out that if you iterate over a vector, using a for loop, you
>   get a reference.

This is actually not true. It depends on your vector. If your vector is a reference, it yields a reference. Otherwise it yields an owned value.

Back to your first question:

```rust
pub fn to_bytes(values: &[u32]) -> Vec<u8> {
    for &(mut value) in values {
        // value will be of type u32
        //...
    }
}
```

This is called [destructuring](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_pointers.html). Since `values` here is of type `&[u32]`, the value it yields with the for loop is of type `&u32`. With the help of `&`, you dereference the pointer so the `value` variable here will be of type `u32`.

Alternatively you can also do the following, but your value will be of type `&u32`.

```rust
pub fn to_bytes(values: &[u32]) -> Vec<u8> {
    for mut value in values {
        // value will be of type &u32
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks about you statement regarding the yielding of reference/value. :)
Regarding the actual answer: It am trying to understand it but I feel it is not so easy. You are saying, that with the help of `&`, I am dereferencing the pointer. I thought that `*` is used for dereferencing (the link says it too). Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh wait: The value which is yielded by the iterator is pattern matched against `mut value`. The `&` is used to destructure the value. I hope that is correct o.O

Comment: Yes. That's correct. * is used in front of the value while & is used in front of the variable .

Comment: Ok cool. Now I get it. Thanks :)

Comment: Please look for duplicate questions and answers before answering.